# Why do I see the blank page?

Tags: php

I am trying to display the data from my table on my page and I have done it many times before. This time it is not working, I usually copy the code from my other projects and change the appropriate values but this time it's not working. Please note I am not quite sure what I am doing. I don't usually write code. This is using iis with php and the database server is mysql. The problem is I get a white page with no errors or other signs.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
require('connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM td";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Comment</th><th>Amount</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    echo "<tr><td style='width: 200px;'>".$date."</td><td style='width: 600px;'>".$comment."</td><td>".$amount."</td></tr>";
} 

echo "</table>"
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Oh and there is data in the table. Also the connection to the db is fine I use the same connection file to insert data to the table.

Wow that fixed it. I knew it was some stupidity on my part I just did notice it.

Comment: Right click on the white page and view source. Sometimes there will be an error to see, but because no style loads, you get white on white.  I had this EXACT thing happen to me just last week.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the source (it could be my server is set to not show errors but that's another problem I will fix later)

Comment: turn on error_reporting and display_errors. white page = they're turned off and something blew up.

Comment: Have PHP print the error for you:
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

Comment: I am really slow with this coding stuff where do I paste that line of code if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); exit(); }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "</table>";
```

you forget the ";"  :D. And if that did not help, maybe the result is empty and there's nothing to show? That may be why you got a white screen.